# Loading and cropping bitmaps without Out Of Memory exception

Tags: android, image

I need to crop images from Facebook, Instagram or the device itself. At the end of the user flow (where he selects them), all the said images should be send to the server. But all in the same width/height ratio (e.g. 3/2), therefore I need to crop the images manually.

Here a simple example of what's going on in my upload service and the cropping:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ImageLoading.getLoader(UploadService.this).loadImageSync(path);
//crop calculations
Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, x, y, w, y);
String croppedPath = saveCroppedImage(croppedBitmap);
```

I then read this file from the filesystem and encode it to BASE64 to send it to the backend.

When I have to do this for multiple images, I regularly get an OOM Exception. Maybe I'm going at this the wrong way.. Cropping on the server side is really the last thing I want to do, because then the backend would have to query Facebook or Instagram.

Loading a scaled version of the bitmap isn't an option, I'm not displaying it on the device.

I have tried:

- System.gc()
- Bitmap.recycle();
- Should I really use largeHeap in my manifest?

note: I'm using Universal Image Loader for the user flow as well, that's why I'm using it in the upload service too.

Comment: GC isn't your problem. Android heaps get fragmented; there is no single free block big enough to satisfy the allocation request. Try to reuse `Bitmap` objects (see `inBitmap` on `BitmapFactory.Options`), which may necessitate doing the image-loading yourself instead of using UIL. Ideally, you would find a way to do the cropping that doesn't involve creating another copy of the image (as `createBitmap()` might do). And there may be things you can do in `saveCroppedImage()` to help as well.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! saveCroppedImage() just uses a FileOutputStream and compresses it to PNG 100. I really can't afford quality loss. I had a look at inBitmap, but that seems to restrict the use of different image sizes.

Comment: "I had a look at inBitmap, but that seems to restrict the use of different image sizes" -- API Level 19+ offers more flexibility, but yes, it's limited. On the other hand, you may not have lots of options, unless you want to start using the NDK and doing the image cropping in C/C++.

Comment: Yes I've noticed it's more flexible on 19+. I'm not really following you how using the NDK can improve memory management here? I might have to rethink the whole approach and do the server sided cropping after all..

Comment: "how using the NDK can improve memory management here?" -- simple: you are not using the Java heap. You have access to the entire free system RAM. If you move load-crop-and-save logic into the NDK, it runs faster and avoids `OutOfMemoryError`. It is more cumbersome to maintain, particularly across CPU architectures. It is also more tedious to test and stuff. But, you may not have a choice. Bear in mind that even if you ask for a `largeHeap`, it may not be very large (e.g., Android One devices).

Comment: Yes it actually sounds like quite some work from what I found online. I will consider it an option, thank you for the explanation!

Comment: try glide or Picasso loading library

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add largeHeap = true in the AndroidManifest file.

Secondly, If you are using Universal ImageLoader, you can download the bitmap in smaller size. Please have a look at this code:

```
ImageSize targetSize = new ImageSize(80, 50); // result Bitmap will be fit to this size
Bitmap bmp = imageLoader.loadImageSync(imageUri, targetSize, options); // This bitmap will be of specified size.
```

You can further read about [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) by following the link.

Comment: Loading a smaller version of the bitmap isn't an option here I'm afraid. We need them full-quality. I thought I might have to use largeHeap, but it sounds like a dirty code.